# Confusion regarding convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have certain doubts about convergence in measure.

We know that, for example, $f_n = \Bbb{1}_{(0,n)}\frac{1}{n} $ converges in Lebesgue measure to zero. That is : $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda( x \in \Bbb{R}:  \vert f_n(x) -  f(x) \vert \gt \alpha ) =  0 $ for every $\alpha \geq 0 $

Now, my doubts begin. Take $\alpha = \frac{1}{9}$

A set that satifies $\vert \Bbb{1}_{(0,n)} \frac{1}{n}\vert \gt \frac{1}{9} $ is the set $(0,8)$ with Lebesgue measure 8. If we take the limit its not zero.

Now, of course, I am confusing something. I would like to know what is my mistake.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing the variables $n$ and $x$.

If $n \geq 9$ then $|1_{(0,n)} (x)\frac  1n|\leq |\frac  1n| \leq \frac 1 9$ for any $x$. So,  $|1_{(0,n)} (x)\frac  1n|>\frac 19$ cannot hold for any $x$ if $n \geq 9$.

Comment: So the set is null?

Comment: Yes, it is the null set, so it has measure $0$. @UDAC